# Dynamically arranging images in a pattern - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, logic

I am working on a project where I have kind of a timeline where user can click on a month and see the medals won for that particular month in a popup. Now, I want for the program to arrange the medal image (small visual circle). The should arrange like this, or something like this (I'm not really particular about one specific format but I just want them to be symmetric):

1. 1 medal - One small circle
2. 2 medals - Two circles side by side
3. 3 medals - Three circles with two side by side and the one on the top-middle of the two medals
4. 4 medals - Four circles forming like a square
5. 5 medals - Four circles in a square and 5th one on the top-middle.

I know I might not have been clear about my requirement so please mention if you need anymore clarification.

**I need the logic to draw this or any other pattern for the medals. I am working in objective-c for the record**

Comment: I would use a switch statement with the count of the medals as input and arrange the image views for the medals accordingly.

Comment: It might be strange solution, but you couldn't you create 5 images of the medals in the right places you have described and use a switch statement like dasdom said to change a UIImageView. Because visually that is what you are doing. Otherwise you have to mess around with CGRects. Just an idea (oh dont forget to make retina images too with @2x in the filename :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like :

```
int nrmedals; //number of medals
CGPoint bottompos; //position of the lower left corner of the rectangle where you want to draw
float padding; //space between medals
float diameter; //diameter of the medals
if (nrmedals%2==0) { //even
    for (int i=0; i<nrmedals; i+=2) {
        draw medal one at position (bottompos.x,bottompos.y+ i/2 * (diameter + padding));
        draw medal two at position (bottompos.x+diameter+padding ,bottompos.y + i/2 * (diameter + padding));

    }

}else {//odd
    for (int i=0; i<nrmedals-1; i+=2) {
        draw medal one at position (bottompos.x,bottompos.y+ i/2 * (diameter + padding));
        draw medal two at position (bottompos.x+diameter+padding ,bottompos.y + i/2 * (diameter + padding));

    }
draw odd medal at position (bottompos.x +diameter/2+padding/2 ,bottompos.y+diameter * (nrmedals-1)/2 +padding);
}
```

this is the basic idea (of course you can replace the "2" with a variable and instead of 2 medals per row you have more)

some of the math calculating the points may be off

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I get 3 medals to work? I will in all probability need 3 medals per row. I tried replacing 2 with a 3 and it didn't work. Also, I get this when I use a bigger number like 19 : http://s7.postimage.org/xgnlcsxez/Screen_Shot_2012_12_10_at_11_44_17_AM.png

Comment: well you need to set in "for" the coord of the 3rd medal relative to the 2nd one. Something like  `draw medal three at position (medal2.x+diameter+padding ,medal2.y + i/2 * (diameter + padding)) ` (you should be able to work the relative coord with a piece of paper and a pen :) ). As for the odd one out you position it on the next row, in the middle..it's simple

Comment: Cool. But then we'll have different odd one outs. We'll have two of those, right?

Comment: @Shukaku for those just take the length of the row and position those at 1/3 and 2/3 (in case of 2 left) or 1/2 (in case of one left). Or in a more general case: (length/(nr of medals left)*(current medal) // current medal is the one you're currently positioning . The formula may change depending on your origin of the image (usually is 0.5, 0.5 of you width and height...i think)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Skytz. How can I change this code so that if I have say 6 medals, I would then have 3 in the bottom row, 2 in the upper row and 1 in the upmost row. If I divide the total number of medals by 3, I'll have them in parellel rows, right? I am weak with logic and would really appreciate some example here. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Shukaku i wrote you what you need [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/txye5pjckayd7ss/NakedNinjas.zip) with example and comments

Comment: That's more than I could ever ask for. Although I tried to convert it to UIKit code. It's alright for some of the medals but not for the others. 6 medals makes a perfect pyramid but when I put 9 into the number of medals, it goes unaligned. I am marking your reply as answer and I wouldn't mind if you don't take a look at the project that I made from your code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmcqee5wc8bg6d1/Medal%20Drawing.zip but if you do get time to review/modify it, I would be really helpful to you for the help. Thanks.

Comment: that's because 9 is not a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). As it stands now the pyramid code works only for these numbers. What you need to do is to check if the number of medals left => basenumber - 1 ...if it is just draw them and subtract ..if not recalculate the position using the code from the last line of the grid thingy( to position the remaining views right on the middle of the next row).